# Error in $gte aggregation expression: "Expression $gte takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in."

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this error while trying

```
db.any.aggregate([
 {  "$project": { n: {$gte: 0}}    }
])
```

I'm sure must be something obvious, but I cannot find the error. Using mongo 3.4 from the shell client

Comment: check [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) syntax you missed key to compare

Answer (score 28, accepted):

here is an example for your reference

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
          {
            qty: { $gte: [ "$qty", 250 ] },

          }
     }
   ]
)
```

**

> note : there is slight difference when you use aggregation framework
>   when compared to the regular querying.

**

querying without aggregation framework

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $gte: 250 } } )
```

References:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html

P.S: Other comparison operators also follow the same difference.

Comment: I see, the relational operators in aggregation $project are different from the same operators in find queries. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. hope it worked for you. if my answer helped you please feel free to accept it. :)